# Unable to Run webserver on centos docker container

Tags: php, apache, docker

I am trying to build a centos docker container with PHP5.6 & Apache2.4. I have created a DockerFile like this -

```
FROM centos:latest
MAINTAINER Rituparna
RUN yum -y groupinstall 'Basic Web Server'
RUN yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
RUN yum install -y http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
RUN yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
RUN yum -y install php php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql php-ldap php-zip php-fileinfo
COPY phpinfo.php /var/www/html/
CMD [“/usr/sbin/httpd”, “-D”, “FOREGROUND”]
EXPOSE 80
```

Then I trigger the following command -

```
#docker build /docker/ -t webserver:v1
```

Docker builder successfully. I checked docker images -

```
# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
webserver           v1                  7653a3ca22df        About an hour ago   1.55 GB
docker.io/httpd     2.4                 e77c77f17b46        2 weeks ago         140 MB
docker.io/centos    latest              9f38484d220f        3 months ago        202 MB
```

Once docker built successful, I ran the docker like this -

```
 # docker run webserver:v1 cat /etc/issue
\S
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Then I run the docker with the following command -

```
# docker run -d -it -p 8080:80 webserver:v1
c4c4e986ef67e1359d0a9c9c99cadb7ad340717c528da24666e36ea8ad1e3643
```

I can able to SSH to Docker container like this -

```
# docker run -it webserver:v1 bash
[root@98c0b59164e3 /]# cd /var/www/html/
[root@98c0b59164e3 html]# ls
phpinfo.php
[root@98c0b59164e3 html]# php -v
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: May 28 2019 10:47:03)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
[root@98c0b59164e3 html]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Apr 24 2019 13:45:48
```

Now while trying to access the docker hosting like this -

```
# links http://192.168.0.10:8080/phpinfo.php
```

It is throwing "Unable to connect". 192.168.0.10 is the IP of HOST SYSTEM. I have also tried to run below command on docker container -

```
# /usr/sbin/httpd -D 'FOREGROUND'
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

still not able to browse the website from the host system or from LAN.

Need some help to identify and fix the issue.

**UPDATE :** *I managed to run docker by adding a Dockerfile with following* -

```
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd"]
```

Comment: Is your host system a linux, or is it a VM on a Windows host ? In the later case, the linux VM running docker has its own, internal IP on a host-only network, that's the IP you want to use to reach your container.

Comment: @lbndev My Host system is CentOS 7. Even from docker "curl localhost" not working.

Comment: can you  connect with http://192.168.0.10:8080/index.html ?

Comment: Sadly NO. This site can’t be reached

Comment: Can you confirm `docker run -d -it --name mytest webserver:v1` then `docker exec -it mytest curl localhost` can't connect ? Or did you use another sequence of commands ? What's the exact output from curl in this case ? Anything in `docker logs mytest` ?

Comment: @lbndev ---- # docker run -d -it --name mytest webserver:v1
c3059703354d592c7b96161e96a4f372d549c23b3f716f6261f988dc405f0538
[root@webserver ~]# docker exec -it mytest webserver:v1
Error response from daemon: Container c3059703354d592c7b96161e96a4f372d549c23b3f716f6261f988dc405f0538 is not running

Comment: try move CMD to the end of line

Comment: @RituparnoBhattacharya Anything in the logs ? If it's not running, it must be because it failed. Logs will tell you why.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `—-network host` to your `docker run` statement. [Example from Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/)